# Car electronics

Tags: engine, power-steering

I am developing system and I have this converter: [Picture](http://www.auctiva.com/hostedimages/showimage.aspx?gid=58170&ppid=1122&image=337921739&images=413553759,413553764,413553772,337921715,337921726,337921739,337921748&formats=0,0,0,0,0,0,0&format=0)

And I need to connect this to car electronic. Where is the best spot to connect this?
Can you post a picture to show me the wires.

Comment: What does the converter connect to? What is the make, model and year of the car?

Comment: It connects power supply of the car PC. This is converter to get straight 12V power because of the engine cracks. I need to know where is the best spot to connect car power supply? I need just a info because I don't have specific car it can be any of it

Comment: Please provide more specifics about the question. All cars are different, and may have different requirements dependent on manufacturer, year, and market where it was sold. Once it is edited, flag for moderators’ attention so that they would consider reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a Automotive 12.5-4.4V adapter to a PC Regulated 12.0V/5.0V ATX adapter for a motherboard (hence the chokes) with a small LED output. The first thing you need to figure out is the wiring input:

- **Red** = +12V?, Ignition/On?
- **Black** = Ground?
- **White** = +12V? Ignition/On?

**+12V Constant** - The power requirement isn't too great (fused at 10A) so I'd target a large diameter +12V constant. If it were me, I'd run my own through the firewall from the battery with a 20A fuse at the battery for it, but you'd probably be just fine with the Yellow / +12V constant behind the radio or at the ignition switch.

**Ignition/On** - The trigger wire is going to switch it on/off, so I myself would put it on a switch I put somewhere, an On/Off/On switch with +12V constant on one side and +12V ignition on at the other. This way I could manually switch it on, off, or on when the key is in.

**Ground** - Run it back to the negative battery terminal if you're a wiring nazi like me, or just crimp a ring terminal on it and screw it into some dash metal with a lock washer.